# cassandra racks & replication factor

Tags: nosql, cassandra, bigdata, cql3

I have 2 CASSANDRA DC's

```
DC1
+-----+
|RAC1 |
+-----+ 
|node1|
+-----+
|node2|
+-----+
|node3|
+-----+
|node4|
+-----+


DC2
+-----+-----+-----+
|RAC1 |RAC2 |RAC3 |
+-----+-----+-----+
|node1|node1|node1|          
+-----+-----+-----+
|node2|node2|node2|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Can I use RF=3 in DC2 or RACK nodes count must be higher than RF?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeReplication_c.html), I think the rule you are referring to is this:

> As a general rule, the replication factor should not exceed the number
>   of nodes in the cluster.

Your replication factor exceeds the number of nodes in each rack, but I think that's ok.  Are you using NetworkTopologyStrategy?  The same doc also indicates that:

> NetworkTopologyStrategy places replicas in the same data center by
>   walking the ring clockwise until reaching the first node in another
>   rack. NetworkTopologyStrategy attempts to place replicas on distinct
>   racks because nodes in the same rack (or similar physical grouping)
>   often fail at the same time due to power, cooling, or network issues.

So if you are using NetworkTopologyStrategy, then I think your replication factor of 3 for DC2 should work just fine.